# How to make include directories added with AUTOUIC available to downstream targets?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have a problem with CMake's AUTOUIC option in my qt project.

I have a target that has *.ui qt-form files and changed it to use the AUTOUIC option to automatically generate the corresponding ui_*.h files and add their location to the target's include directory.

The problem is, that I inlcude the generated "ui_*.h" file in a header of the target, which is then included in another test-target. The test-target however does not have the directory with the generated files set to its include directories and therefore will not find the ui_*.h file.

So is there any way to get the directory of the generated files so I can add it to the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of my first target. When I do this using hardcoded names It solves my compile errors, but I would rather do this by getting that directory from some target property or so. I failed with that because the AUTOUIC include dirs seem to be added only after processing all the CMakeLists files.

Btw., I am currently using CMake 3.8.2, but updating to 3.9 is an option if the problem has been solved there.

Comment: To solve the issues I went back to using the manual wrapping with ````qt5_wrap_ui()````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From CMake version 3.9 onwards you can use the following snippet to add the autogenerated headers to a target's build interface include directories:

```
get_property(_isMultiConfig GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
if(_isMultiConfig)
  set(AUTOGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}_autogen/include_$<CONFIG>)
else()
  set(AUTOGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}_autogen/include)
endif()

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${AUTOGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}>
)
```

See:

- [Use GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG to detect multi-config generators](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1627?commit_id=3c413e2a31b4fcb6a99dba04669c6a6517b97832)
- [AUTOUIC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html)
- [GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html)
- [AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR.html#prop_tgt:AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR)

Comment: I am not sure if I will find the time to verify this solution. If somebody else says that it works, I will choose it as answer.

Comment: @Knitschi For me this seems to have done the trick. It must be noted though, that `TARGET_NAME` has to be defined beforehand (obviously). E.g. `set(TARGET_NAME "myTarget")`

Comment: @globberwops FYI: I also copied your proposal to the cmake bug report created by xflowXen (with credit to you, of course)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue - it looks like a bug in CMAKE (I'm using version 3.10 rc5)
and have opened a bug report to CMAKE here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17456

In the meantime you can copy the autgenerated header files to your project source directory by using the following commands after autouic has been run.

```
SET(AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR "${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/<project>_autogen/include_${CONFIG}") 
file(COPY "${AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR}/ui_xxxx.h" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/headers")
```

where ${CONFIG} is the type of build (Debug/Release)

Comment: I want to keep generated files out of my source tree if possible. So I guess I wait until the problem gets fixed. But thank you for filing the bug. I guess I should have done that back then.